# Data structure to find farthest point from a point set in logarithmic time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

I have a set P of n points in 2-dimensional space. I have to perform the following query on these points:

*Given a set X which is a subset of P, find a point in set P\X, which has the maximum distance to all points in X. In order words, find a point y in P\X that maximizes the distance between y and any point in X.*

I have to perform the query a lot of times. I can perform the query in O(n^2) time by checking all pairwise distance. I am looking for a data structure that gives the query output in logarithmic time.  Also, I want to build the data structure in less than O(n^2) time.

NB: For any set P of n points, using point location in a furthest point Voronoi diagram of P, for any point q we can find its furthest point in P in logarithmic time. ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153637/how-to-find-the-farthest-point-from-a-set-of-points-from-a-given-point-efficie))

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried point location data structure (point location in a furthest point Voronoi diagram). But I am not sure how that helps my query in logarithmic time.

Comment: Then please add a description about your effort to the question - some users may downvote the question otherwise.

Comment: Do you want to maximize the distance between `y` and the point in `X` nearest to `y`? Or the farthest one? Or the average distance? Also, is an approximate solution acceptable?

Comment: I want to maximize the distance between a point y in P\X to the farthest point in X. I am looking for an exact solution. A similar problem is: Given two sets (X, Y) of points, find a pair of points (x,y)  where x is in X, y is in Y, and the distance between x,y is minimized.

Comment: If you build a new farthest-neighbour Voronoy diagram for every query, and then apply the algorithm from the link to every point in `P\X`, it gives you `O(n*log(n))` time and `O(n)` space. This is almost as fast as it can get, considering that just reading the query takes `O(n)`.

Comment: Reading the query takes time proportional to the size of X, which is not necessarily proportional to the size of P.